# Does every class need an entry in JSHint globals?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jshint

Every time I create a new `ES6`-class I need to add it to the `globals` in the `.jshintrc`. Because otherwise I get the warning `W117 '<classname>' is not defined`.

The project is not huge, so adding each class to the `globals` is not a big deal. Anyway I am wondering how bigger projects with thousand of classes and many developers avoid this, because the list gets long and is probably not manageable.

To find a solution I looked at the `JSHint` options and tried to find hints on the Internet, but I could not find anything useful.

*Example:*

Create new class (in own file).

```
/* exported Foo*/
class Foo {
  // some code
}
```

Use new class in another file.

```
const foo = new Foo(); // W117 'Foo' is not defined
```

After adding `Foo` to the `globals` the warning disappears.

```
// .jshintrc
{
    // some options

    "globals": {
        "Foo": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using any kind of module system, or are you using many separate JS files with a <script> for each? Generally modern build tools assume modular code, so in your example `Foo` would have to be explicitly imported and exported, meaning it wouldn't be global, and wouldn't need to be referenced in the linting config.

Comment: At the moment I have many separate JS files which I concatenate during the Grunt run. After I have seen 喝茶的螃蟹 answer I tried to use ES6 modules, but this leads to problems because of the concatenation. So the next step is to find out, how to use the modules properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [ES6 Modules](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html).
At the moment you create a Class Foo but you do not export it.

```
class Foo{
    ...
}

export default Foo;
```

Before using Foo, you should import it

```
import Foo from './foo.js'

const foo = new Foo();
```